# Unable to edit users profile

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

When I  try and edit a users info nothing happens after clicking 'update' except for the url showing an authenticity token at the end. The logs show an unpermitted parameters error that looks like this:

```
 Unpermitted parameters: utf8, _method, authenticity_token, user, commit, format
```

I changed the devise routes to add omniauth signups as well as a custom devise controller for a separate edit view. 
The routes:

```
devise_for :users, path_names: {sign_in: "login", sign_out: "logout"},
               controllers: {omniauth_callbacks: "omniauth_callbacks"}

devise_scope :user do
get "/info" => "registrations#info"
end
```

Here is the custom devise controller:

```
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
def info
    @user = current_user
    if @user 
        render :info
    else
        redirect_to root_path
     end 
    end

   def update
    @user = User.find(params[:id])


  @user.update_without_password(devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:account_update))
 redirect_to user_path(current_user)

 end
 protected

 def after_sign_up_path_for(resource)
   '/info'
  end
 end
```

and here is the edit view:

```
<%= simple_form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => registration_path(resource_name), :html => { :method => :put}) do |f| %>

 <%= f.input :name %>
 <%= f.input :email %>

<% end %>
```

Comment: Please update the question with the relevant server log including `params` hash and `unpermitted params` warning.

Comment: Updated, thanks. Is that what you wanted?

Comment: Let's discuss this on chat http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48530/ror

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the chat session, OP had two `forms` as :

```
<form class="form-horizontal"> 
<form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/users" class="simple_form user" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="edit_user" method="post"><div style="margin:0;padding:0;display:inline"><input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="&#x2713;" /><input name="_method" type="hidden" value="put" /><input name="authenticity_token" type="hidden" value="om7WhULk2OPgMGwjbTz5h79BqUlkr4lF9aRVDaOxUhs=" /></div>
```

Suggested to remove `<form class="form-horizontal">` and add the class to the existing `simple_form_for` as below:

```
<%= simple_form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => registration_path(resource_name), :html => { :method => :put}, :class =>"form-horizontal") do |f| %>
```

Also, to update user record without password, change the update action as below:

```
  def update
    # For Rails 4
    account_update_params = devise_parameter_sanitizer.sanitize(:account_update)

    # required for settings form to submit when password is left blank
    if account_update_params[:password].blank?
      account_update_params.delete("password")
      account_update_params.delete("password_confirmation")
    end

    @user = User.find(current_user.id)
    if @user.update_attributes(account_update_params)
      set_flash_message :notice, :updated
      # Sign in the user bypassing validation in case his password changed
      sign_in @user, :bypass => true
      redirect_to user_path(current_user)
    else
      render "edit"
    end
  end
```

**UPDATE**

Your current call is going to "Processing by Devise::RegistrationsController#update as HTML "
`Devise::RegistrationsController` instead of your `RegistrationsController`
Update the `routes.rb` as below:

```
devise_for :users, path_names: {sign_in: "login", sign_out: "logout"}, 
controllers: {omniauth_callbacks: "omniauth_callbacks", registrations: :registrations}
```